# "String" infinity paradox

Tags: string-theory

The smallest particles of the universe (or the smallest part of the smallest particles of the universe) must have infinity density. But if it have infinity density, you can calculate mass of one of these particles as infinity - so if any thing would composed of these particles, would it have infinity mass. How is it possible?

Comment: Infinite density together with zero volume could be finite mass.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is called [Quantum Mechanics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_mechanics) .

Physics is the discipline of modeling measurements ( called data) with mathematical theories. By the nature of modeling there are limits of application. In the beginning of the modern physics era when the beautiful theories of Classical Mechanics, Thermodynamics and  Electromagnetism were first proposed with consistent mathematical tools this was not very clear. There was a time when physicists of the 19th century thought they had solved physics , i.e. how nature works, and it would from then on be all applications and engineering. They were wrong.

New data proved them wrong. The photoelectric effect that clearly showed light to have a particle nature, the table of elements showing the atomic structure, the spectral lines emitted from elements etc all pointed to more and new physics regimes not covered by the  classical theories/models.

The Bohr model tried to explain why the electrons did not fall into the nucleus and disappear by postulating arbitrary rules of quantized energy levels. It was only when the equations of quantum mechanics were modeled on the data that it became clear that in the microcosm nature follows quantum dynamical rules and the classical picture emerges from the quantum mechanical substructure.

So this is wrong:

> The smallest particles of the universe (or the smallest part of the smallest particles of the universe) must have infinity density .

Quantum mechanics limits the "smallness" of small particles by its probabilistic nature. Quantum mechanics also says the only thing we can know is a measurement.

In a generic way this is seen in the [Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_uncertainty):

[image: HUP]   the HUP

How can we tell the size of a particle? The experimental way is by scattering light or other particles against it, and measure the result.

The HUP says that if you measure the x location of a particle, i.e. find the size very small as in your hypothesis, the momentum of the particle will grow to the point of indeterminacy.

So even though the current particle physics [Standard Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) treats the basic elementary particles as point particles some of which have mass, the problem does not arise because one will never be able to locate such a particle to such small dimensions.

Comment: anna v: "_Physics is the discipline of modeling measurements (called data) with mathematical theories._" -- No: that's at most some part of physics (and indeed a part of physics about which I admittedly know little). However: Experimental Physics is the discipline of deriving measured values (in particular: real number values or Boolean values) from given/incidental observational data.

Comment: @user12262 I am talking of the whole of physics, of which I think I know enough. Physic's holy grail is in constructing a mathematical theory that fits all  existing data from experiments and will predict all possible outcomes of experiments. Experimental physics is the chore of gathering the data and validating or falsifying  physics theories. At least at this day and age.

Comment: anna v: "_[...] predict all possible outcomes of experiments._" -- Well, that's seems conjugate to the (true! ;) experimentalist's approach of first ridding oneself entirely of any expectations. "_Experimental physics is the chore of gathering the data_" -- ... that's the easy/inevitable part. The hard part (I repeat) is to derive Boolean values; or at least real values; or at least finite real confidence intervals from that. "_and validating or falsifying physics theories._" -- No; but as you suggsted yourself (see quote in my previous comment): validating or falsifying physics models.

Comment: @foggy Every particle is a different "eigenstate" of a string, the way the theory is developing at the moment.

Comment: @user12262 Physics theories are mathematical models. They are theories because they have postulates over and above the internal mathematical consistency of the models used.

Comment: @anna v: "_Physics theories are mathematical models. [...]_" -- Theories are systems of axioms/postulates/definitions and the sentences/theorems which can consequently be expressed. For theories of physics, the definitions are concerned especially with quantities to be measured; and thus with the [value range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_%28mathematics%29) of measurement operators. In contrast, models of physics summarize specific values which were actually obtained, and/or which are expected. Importantly: models can be experimentally falsified (or corroborated), while theories can not.

Comment: @user12262 In my books all "physics theories" can be falsified by data. Other wise they are not physics theories, they may be beautiful mathematical constructs useful for finding physics theories that will fit the data. For example Thermodynamics: it has laws that are falsified at the microscopic level, i.e. it does not apply there. It is a model/theory  of physics for a specific range of physical variables. Outside of that it is mathematics. Classical Mechanics : its postulates are falsified in the region of special relativity . etc. You are thinking of "phenomenological models" .

Comment: @anna v: "_In my books all "physics theories" can be falsified by data._" -- In my books all "physical models" can be falsified **based on** observational data; but not "_by_ (abstract or raw) _data_" as such, but instead by measured values **derived from** collected raw data. Models which haven't been falsified yet are often called "standard models" (of particle physics, of cosmology, etc.). But the definitions of quantities to be measured, i.e. of **how to measure** (in principle, or otherwise for assessing systematic uncertainties) are not falsifiable based on data. (to be contd.)

Comment: (contd. (sorry for the delay)) @anna v: "_You are thinking of "phenomenological models"_" -- Fair enough, in default of any other more appropriate entry in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model "_For example Thermodynamics: it has laws that are falsified at the microscopic level, i.e. it does not apply there._" -- Are the notions in terms of which those "_laws of TD_" are expressed even defined "_at the microscopic level_"? Can the corresponding quantities be evaluated at all, given such data? Are "_microscopic_ states" eigenstates of the corresponding measurement operators? ...

Answer (score 0):

My answer to this question may seem very simple but it's the basic.
Density=Mass/Volume as you know an infinitesimally small particle will have infinitesimally small mass and volume.That means your numerator and denominator both are approaching to zero (but not exactly zero) so in that case you will have to apply limit (as for 0/0 form) to get density which will give you a finite value of density.

Comment: The limit might or might not be finite depending on the functions one differentiates to get to the limit. A model is necessary in this case